# Planet, Moon and a Clipping Arc in Canvas - Rough Edges

Tags: javascript, canvas

So I have a rotating `canvas` element which has an arc drawn inside it (the smaller planet):
http://jsfiddle.net/neuroflux/9L689/4/ (updated)

But I can't seem to get the anti-aliasing on the edges of the smaller planet smoother - any ideas?

Cheers!

**edit:** is there a way to increase the number of iterations used within an `arc`?

Comment: images and scripts are 404ing!

Comment: Apologies - updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not that the arc doesn't have enough points, but that in Chrome the `.clip()` operation doesn't use anti-aliasing to produce the clipping path.

See Chromium Issues [7508](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=7508) and [132442](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=132442)

To see this in action, look at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/YMtdZ/ in Chrome.

markup:

```
<canvas id="c" width="600" height="300" />
```

​
code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillStyle = 'black';

ctx.save();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(150, 150, 140, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.clip();
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 300);
ctx.restore();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(450, 150, 140, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
```

​The left-hand circle is drawn with clipping, and is aliased.  The right-hand circle is drawn "normally", and is anti-aliased.

FWIW, in Firefox and Safari both images look the same.  I can't test it on IE.

The only work around I can imagine (until Chrome gets fixed) would be to render the image off-screen into a canvas 3 or 4 times larger, and then copy that with down-sampling into the displayed canvas.